# OpenID not working properly

Tags: asp.net, authentication, openid

I made openID login for my loginpage . Now it showing OpenID providers Images . When i click on it, it not redirect to right page.

More - When i log to Stackoverflow i used google image button. then it redirect to gmail sign in page . but my example it not redirecting

I followed [the tutorial](http://bhaidar.net/post/2011/04/04/OpenID-Single-Sign-On-ASPNET-Web-Forms.aspx)

When i click on Google/Yahoo/AOL it not redirect to above login page .